# Proof sequence converges with monotonocity and boundedness of subsequences without induction?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $a_0 = 0$ and $a_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$ for $n\geq1$.

**I need to proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists.**

I first try to proof $(a_{2n+1})_{n\geq0}$ is decreases monotonously, here I'm in doubt how to make the proof "closed". I currently have this, but I don't know if this actually proofs it.

> $n+1>n$, then $a_{2(n+1)+1}=a_{2n+3}=a_{2n+1} +\sum_{2n+2}^{2n+3}=a_{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+3}<a_{2n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So $(a_{2n+1})_{n\geq0}$ montonously decreasing.

The proof for $(a_{2n})_{n\geq0}$ montonously increasing follows analogously.

I then think I have to proof that these are bounded below and bounded above respectively, and thereby convergent.

From there on I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sequence $(a_{2n-1})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ decreases and the sequence $(a_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ increases. Now, note that\begin{align}a_{2n-1}&=1-\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{2n-1}\\&>1-\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}\\&=a_{2n}\\&\geqslant a_2.\end{align}So, yes, the sequence $(a_{2n-1})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded. Since it is also monotonic, it converges. By the same argument, the sequence $(a_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges too. Now, it's all a matter of proving that the limits are the same. This is easy, since $a_{2n-1}-a_{2n}=\frac1{2n}\to0$.

Comment: But is my proof for monotonocity of $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{2n}$ correct? I'm not confident it actually proofs it. Don't I need induction and why?

Comment: No, you don't need induction and, yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: For proving that the limits are the same, I only use algebra like this, the previously obtained results are not required for this? $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_{2n+1} - a_{2n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2n+2}}{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} = 0$.

Comment: Your proof of the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{2n+1}-a_{2n})=0$ is correct. But now you kneed to know the both limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}$ exist in order to deduce that they are equal.

Comment: @TheCodingWombat: the proof technique used in this particular example is used to prove the general Leibniz test for convergence of alternating series.